# username regex in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I am trying to find a regex to limit what a person can use for a username on my site.  I don't need to have it check to see how many characters there are in it, as another validation does this.  Basically all I need to make it do is make sure that it allows: letters (capital and lowercase) numbers, dashes and underscores.

I came across this: /^[-a-z]+$/i

But it doesn't seem to allow numbers.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/ is a great site for testing your regex.

Comment: This is really basic regex. What you posted includes `a-z`; what do you think you might add to include the numbers 0 to 9?

Comment: well i apologize, i am having trouble finding good rails regex resources on the web.  I would think something like this: ^[-a-z]+[-0-9]$

Comment: but that requires you to have a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression contains a *character class* `[-a-z]` that allows the characters `-` (dash) and `a` through `z`. In order to expand the range of characters allowed by this character class, you will need to add more characters within the `[]`.

Please see [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for further information and examples.

Answer (score 5):

The regex you're looking for is

```
/\A[a-z0-9\-_]+\z/i
```

Meaning one or more characters of range a-z, range 0-9, - (needs to be escaped with a backslash) and _, case insensitive (the i qualifier)

Comment: Just as a point of clarification: the hyphen doesn't *necessarily* need to be escaped. You can also put it in a place where it is considered "meaningless" (impossible to create a range) such as the first or last letter of the character class (like in the OP's original regex).

Comment: Correct. It needs to be escaped in this particular arrangement.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
/\A[\w-]+\z$/
```

`\w` is shorthand for letters, digits and underscore.

`\A` matches at the start of the string, `\z` matches at the end of the string. These tokens are called [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), and Ruby is a bit special with regard to them: Most regex engines use `^` and `$` as start/end-of-string anchors by default, whereas in Ruby they can also match at the start/end of lines (which matters if you're working with multiline strings). Therefore, it's safer (as @JustMichael pointed out) to use `\A` and `\z` because there is no such ambiguity.

Comment: I think it's more safe to use /\A[\w-]+\z/ instead